# Unable to click and capture the correct xpath of an image using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on the that appears after clicking in box that opens after clicking on an expand icon. Using Webdriver I am able to expand the box but after that I am unable to click on the image icon which suposed to open a dialog box.

The xpath is showing for that image is as follows:
`html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[14]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/img`

The code is coming as:

```html
<div id="isc_X1" style="POSITION:relative;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:205382;CURSOR:default;" eventproxy="page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$VerticalLayout1">
<div id="isc_X2" class="normal" onscroll="return page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$customerInteractionSearchGrid.$lh()" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 717px; height: 64px; z-index: 205400; margin: 0px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden;" eventproxy="page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$customerInteractionSearchGrid">
<div id="isc_Y8" class="normal" onscroll="return page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$MenuLayout.$lh()" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 64px; width: 800px; height: 18px; z-index: 205454; padding: 0px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; cursor: default;" eventproxy="page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$MenuLayout">
<div id="isc_Y9" style="POSITION:relative;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:205454;CURSOR:default;" eventproxy="page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$MenuLayout">
<div id="isc_YB" class="imgButton" onscroll="return page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$ImageAdd.$lh()" style="position: absolute; left: 782px; top: 0px; width: 18px; height: 18px; z-index: 205472; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;" tabindex="7583" onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.blurFocusCanvas(page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$ImageAdd,true);" onfocus="if(event.target!=this)return;isc.EH.focusInCanvas(page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$ImageAdd,true);" role="button" eventproxy="page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$ImageAdd">
<div id="isc_YA" style="POSITION:relative;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:205472;CURSOR:pointer;" eventproxy="page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$ImageAdd">
<img border="0" align="TEXTTOP" height="18" width="18" suppress="TRUE" name="isc_YApage$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$ImageAdd" src="http://kolcaresuse01:12345/cwf/r/orga_pics/add_icon.gif?v=1371640285409en-xx"/>
```

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use shorter locators if possible, `//tag[@attribute_name='attribute_value']` for example
2. You need to use explicit and implicit waits. They're discribed [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

If I understand your code right, the `<img>` is in `<div id="isc_YA" style="POSITION:relative;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:205472;CURSOR:pointer;" eventproxy="page$mainWindow$interactionsUI$$content$InteractionDetail$ImageAdd">` tag. So here's the python example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

## Here you're expanding the box, then:

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains (@id, 'constant_part_of_id')]/img").is_displayed(), "No icon displayed")
## 5 is for 5 seconds to wait
## driver is for instance of webdriver
## check the locator, it might be wrong
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains (@id, 'constant_part_of_id')]/img").click()
## Or whatever you're going to do with that
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Still it did not work for me. The id of the div is constantly changing everytime. I have used following JAVa code instead:

Comment: @user2530711 I've edited code a little. For dynamic attribute's values you can use `contains` method in your locators. Can't see your code, btw. And AFAIK, be awawre that in JAVA time argument is for milliseconds

Comment: Or you can use another locator
`"//div[contains (@eventproxy, 'ImageAdd')]//img"`
In general you must find right locator. Use firepath extension for FF, as @djangofan said

Answer (score 0):

I would use [FluentWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) instead of WebDriverWait because it sounds like you may be getting a exception that you need to handle/ignore until the element is ready to be acted upon.   Also, @AlexanderPetrovich is correct and you should use a shortened locator or perhaps a css locator instead.   Also, I would use the Firefox plugin "FirePath" to verify your locator syntax.

Comment: I still think that WebDriverWait should be fine. If you need o handle an exception you could do: `try: return WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(blah-blah-blah) except (your, exceptions, to, handle): another blah-blah-blah`

Comment: True, if you don't like Martin Fowler's fluent api syntax, then coding it the typical way, using a loop and try-catch also makes a nicely readable test.